# Error with Maven building existing Groovy project

Tags: maven, groovy, java

I want to reproduce the branch iswc13 from the following github project: https://github.com/linqs/KnowledgeGraphIdentification/tree/master.
I clone the project locally and then I switch to the iswc13 branch. 
My environment is Ubuntu 16.04, Maven 3.3.9 and Openjdk version "1.8.0_121". 
I need help since I'm getting the following error when I try to compile the project.

```
Downloading: http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-eclipse-batch/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-eclipse-batch/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-batch/maven-metadata.xml from/to codehaus.org (http://repository.codehaus.org): repository.codehaus.org: Name or service not known
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-batch/maven-metadata.xml from/to codehaus-snapshots (http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots/): nexus.codehaus.org: Name or service not known
[INFO] Using Groovy-Eclipse compiler to compile both Java and Groovy files
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/caleb/workspace/KnowledgeGraphIdentification/nell_lazy/target/classes
Annotation processing got disabled, since it requires a 1.6 compliant JVM
----------
1. ERROR in /home/caleb/workspace/KnowledgeGraphIdentification/nell_lazy/src/main/java/edu/umd/cs/psl/kgi/RunKGI.groovy (at line 1)
    package edu.umd.cs.psl.kgi;
    ^
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
----------
2. ERROR in /home/caleb/workspace/KnowledgeGraphIdentification/nell_lazy/src/main/java/edu/umd/cs/psl/kgi/RunKGI.groovy (at line 1)
    package edu.umd.cs.psl.kgi;
    ^
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
----------
2 problems (2 errors)[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Found 2 errors and 0 warnings.
[INFO] 1error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.569 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-30T18:06:48+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/315M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile (default-compile) on project kgi: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Found 2 errors and 0 warnings.
```

When I run mvn compile -X I have the following:

```
[INFO] Using Groovy-Eclipse compiler to compile both Java and Groovy files
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/caleb/workspace/KnowledgeGraphIdentification/nell_lazy/target/classes
Annotation processing got disabled, since it requires a 1.6 compliant JVM
----------
1. ERROR in /home/caleb/workspace/KnowledgeGraphIdentification/nell_lazy/src/main/java/edu/umd/cs/psl/kgi/RunKGI.groovy (at line 1)
    package edu.umd.cs.psl.kgi;
    ^
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
----------
2. ERROR in /home/caleb/workspace/KnowledgeGraphIdentification/nell_lazy/src/main/java/edu/umd/cs/psl/kgi/RunKGI.groovy (at line 1)
    package edu.umd.cs.psl.kgi;
    ^
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
----------
2 problems (2 errors)[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Found 2 errors and 0 warnings.
[INFO] 1error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.499 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-30T18:15:54+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/307M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile (default-compile) on project kgi: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Found 2 errors and 0 warnings.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile (default-compile) on project kgi: Compilation failure
Found 2 errors and 0 warnings.

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
Found 2 errors and 0 warnings.

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:656)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: could you share the groovy class that throws this error and if it tests a specific class then that as well.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/linqs/KnowledgeGraphIdentification/blob/iswc13/nell_lazy/src/main/java/edu/umd/cs/psl/kgi/RunKGI.groovy) is the class that throws this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a Java version issue. The project was done with a previous version of Java and was not working with my current settings, i.e.,Openjdk version "1.8.0_121". I had to use a `pom.xml` [file](https://github.com/linqs/KnowledgeGraphIdentification/blob/2490dcb02a6a1a38e70b6b73ce8a28af38c7ee67/nell/pom.xml-java8) made for Java 1.8. I replaced the current one with this and it compiled successfully.